# LARAVEL: Al crear un formulario con campos dinámicos(Producto y Entregados)

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, xampp

tengo un formulario en el cual puedo agregar productos que solicito y productos que me autorizan, estos dos deben ser dinamicos, ya los puedo registar y mostrar pero no puedo editarlos me marca un error:
[image: Aqui es donde agrego los productos que pedi y en la parte de abajo los que fueron autorizados por el jefe de almacen]

A la hr de editar me marca un error [image: Este es el error que me sale al querer editar añadiendo mas campos al formulario]

CODIGO QUE OCUPO POR AHORA

public function update(Request $request, Apoyo $apoyo)
    {
        $apoyo->update($request->all());

```
    $productos = array();
    $count = count($request->get('productos'));
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $count ; $i++ ) {
    $productos[] = Producto::create($request->get('productos')[$i])->id; 

  }




    $entregados = array();
    $count = count($request->get('entregados'));
    for($a = 0 ; $a < $count ; $a++ ) {
    $entregados[] = Entregado::create($request->get('entregados')[$a])->id; 

  }
  //dd($productos);



    $apoyo->productos()->sync($productos);
    $apoyo->entregados()->sync($entregados);

    //dd($request);


    return redirect()->route('apoyos.edit', $apoyo->id)
      ->with('info', 'Apoyo actualizado con exito');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuve un problema similar. 
El problema va a estar en los índices de los array, no van a estar consecutivos 0, 1, 2 etc van a estar salteados 0,2,3,5 por eso falla el for.

Si haces un dd($request->get('productos')); o al otro array que manejas vas a ver lo que te mencioné.

Una posible solución es hacer un sort(), con el acomodas los índices

```
$arrayProd = $request->get('productos');
 sort($arrayProd, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Luego hacer el for con el array $arrayProd y hacer lo mismo con los entregados.

La segunda es que hagas un foreach para recorrer el array como lo tienes y dentro pones la variable $I que incremente con cada vuelta.

Comment: Buen dia, hice las soluciones que me ofreces pero no me funcionaron :(, en unos casos me deja agregar pero no me las guarda en la base de datos pero aun asi me las sigue mostrando, no se si me explico, en cuanto al array no me los muestra como tu dices, de hecho me aparecen 25 26 y cuando ingreso un nuevo valor 1:
25 26 1

Comment: Puedes poner un pantallazo del contenido del array para poderte ayudar mejor, porque no pones los índices que es lo que necesitamos, va a estar complicado.

Answer (score 0):

si entiendo la pregunta, lo que buscas es que el valor del producto en el formulario coincida con el id de la tabla productos, de esa manera a la hora de guardar los registros cada uno tendrá el id correspondiente.
Puedes usar el método pluck() de las colecciones laravel haciendo Product::pluck('name','id') esto solo retornará el nombre del producto y el id asi podrás ponerlo en tu formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Especificando un poco la respuesta anterior (de Mundoco), que es la mas acertada,puede que los indices no estén ordenados o que no sean numéricos pero creo que no es el caso, por lo que puedes usar un foreach de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach($arr = $request->get('productos') as $item){
    $productos[] = Producto::create($item)->id;
}
```

Comment: Ayudaría expliques tu aporte

Comment: como dice uno de los comentarios puede que el array no este ordenado respecto a los indices, pero también puede ser que los indices no sean numéricos pero creo que no es el caso, por lo que la mejor manera seria recorrerlos con un foreach, asi como el ejemplo que te puse, recorres todo el array array y en vez de acceder por medio de indices ya accedes a cada elemento que en este caso es el $item

Comment: Procura editar y agregar esos detalles a tu respuesta

Comment: creo que si lo mencioné xD, la parte que dice especificando un poco la respuesta anterior me refería a ese comentario (al de Mundoco)

Comment: Bueno la recomendación se da por ya van tres respuestas y los demás no sabrán a cual te refieres por eso lo mejor es que los detalles queden en tu respuesta y no en los comentarios

Comment: ah ok entiendo, creí que me lo decías para la próxima vez jajaja xD, disculpa ya lo edito.